# Is there any difference between the terms Desktop applications and GUI applications or both means the same?

Tags: qt, user-interface, desktop-application

If i develop a GUI application of a calculator using Qt designer then how will it be different from the calculator application installed on my desktop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From development/deployment point of view and generally there is no difference between calculator app you developed and Calc app shipped by your OS (on your desktop);

GUI apps could be Desktop apps ... Web apps ... any app with user GUI.
In very short!
Desktop apps are generally GUI apps while there is no limitation or restriction ...they are generally user interface apps that show a user GUI and designed to run from user desktop .. 
I think the term "Desktop app" was emphasized back after emergence and to distinguish them from "**Web Applications**" .. the difference being evident and to say Desktop apps run only on user desktop be it single or multi-user software; Web apps run on user browser .. they have server extensions ...etc. 
Desktop apps also are different from Utility/Tools applications (Drivers, Libraries .. background daemon ...etc).